Help with User Authentication after Upgrading to 24.04.1
I tried to upgrade from 22.04, and it successfully upgraded. The only problem, and it's a huge one, is that I cannot login, I get an incorrect login, authentication error, sorry try again. This happens when I want to enter the password of my users. I can not use sudo, cannot switch to root using su or sudo -i.
I can go to recovery and work as a root, though, so I tried changing passwords, but it did not fix the problem.
I checked /etc/pam.d/sudo and /etc/shadow, checked locale and caps, all seem fine.
What else could be the problem? I am under the impression that polkit could be the reason, but I have no clue whatsoever how to check that. Appreciate any ideas

Please try fresh installing Ubuntu 24.04. This upgrade nuked the installation of many users. You can use the live USB to backup data in home folder

I managed to fix the problem by copying /etc/pam.d/ directory from my Ubuntu 22.04 backup. I didn't bother to check which files were specifically modified by the upgrade process. So I just overwrote the whole directory.
Now I have a fully functional Ubuntu 24.04.1 up and running 
